# file_get_contents with Variable

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

Hey so I'm having a slight dilemma with getting the contents of a file using a variable.

So to explain the code below a little, the respform fetches JSON array all ok. And the results url when echo'd displays like a normal URL that when viewed displays JSON data. Then I want to fetch JSON data from the second URL. If I use this variable in file_get_contents nothing happens. If I simply create a variable $url = '' and type the same address it works fine.

I've var dumped the $resulturl variable that I'm using and it is a string(56). I've tried using json_encode and it becomes a string(64). What sort of data does it need to be to be accepted into the file_get_contents.

```
$resp = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
$respform = json_decode($resp, TRUE);
$resulturl = $respform['resultsUrl'];

$data = file_get_contents($resulturl, FALSE);
$insta_array = json_decode($data, TRUE);
print_r($insta_array);
```

Hope someone can help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$resulturl` apparently contains a JSON-encoded URL. You need to do:

```
$resulturl = json_decode($respform['resultsUrl']);
```

Comment: I just tried this but I var_dumped the value of resulturl just after and it returned a value of "NULL"

Comment: Then go one step backward (as many times as needed) until you find a successful/expected outcome, then code forward from that point.  Please show us (in an edit to your question) all of the check points in this task.  Echo and var_export after every variable that you declare.

Comment: @JackEllis The `var_dump()` output you showed in the comment really looks like JSON, so I'm not sure why this didn't work.